# Droppages image not rendering when using HTML img tag

Tags: html, css, image, dropbox

The [droppages](https://www.droppages.com) folder setup is such that the filepaths are

```
/Content/webpage.txt
/Public/main.css
/Public/image.png
```

Initially I had used CSS to place the image on the page:

```
body#idname {
    background: #ffffff url("image.png") no-repeat center right;
    margin-right: 200px;
}
```

(essentially following [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background_shorthand)), which worked to get the image to show up but left the layout all screwy. In looking to see whether `float` can be used with `background-image`, I read through a few questions on here that indicated HTML would be more appropriate since this particular image falls more under content than theme. So now my CSS looks like

```
img#idname {
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    margin-top: 400px 40px 100px;
    height: 282px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

and, for the corresponding HTML, I've tried

```
<img id="idname" src="/Public/image.png" alt="alt text description">
<img id="idname" src="Public/image.png" alt="alt text description">
<img id="idname" src="../image.png" alt="alt text description">
<img id="idname" src="image.png" alt="alt text description">
<img id="idname" src="/image.png" alt="alt text description">
<img id="idname" src="./image.png" alt="alt text description">
```

plus each of the above variations with `id` coming after `src` and `alt` instead of before (does that make a difference?) and putting the DropBox share link in for the `src` (which is what I did with the `<audio>` tag on another page). I've also tried renaming `webpage.txt` and then naming it back again to force DropBox to reset the cache as that's a common issue with these setups, as well as renaming `image.png` — all to no avail. The alt text is the most I can get to show up:

Firefox renders the alt text and nothing else. Inspect element > network tab > shows a 404 for the image.

Safari renders a border with the "no image" icon in the center. Inspect element > network tab > shows "404 Page not found" for the image file and "304 Not modified" for the CSS file.

Dolphin browser on Android also renders a border but with the alt text inside of it; the default browser renders much like Safari. I tried `about:debug` in both but didn't get very far with either browser; the image is clearly 404ing but I'm not sure what the stylesheet's doing on mobile.

I'm guessing I need to fix my code, I just don't know where or what I've messed up. Help please?